# SSH2 to a remote machine via a webpage (html and php)

Tags: php, linux, ssh, phpseclib, ssh2-exec

I am trying to connect to a remote linux machine via a web page, submit a command and view its output on the webpage itself.

This is what i have done so far (after every step I echo a text, just so i can follow up with where the code can reach)

The code gets as far as "2. phpseclib included\n" if excuted from the webpage

if i run this code on a terminal it reaches the end!

```
<html> 
<body> 

  TEST <br/>

<?php

echo "1. start\n";
define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib1.0.0');
include('Net/SSH2.php');


echo "2. phpseclib included\n";
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('HOSTNAME');
echo "3. after Net_SSH2\n";

if (!$ssh->login("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")) {
        echo "4. login failed";
        exit('Login Failed');
    } else {
       echo "4. login gained\n";
    }

echo "5. after login\n";


    if (!($stream = $ssh->exec("ls"))) {
            echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
        } else {
          echo $stream;
            }

         if (!($stream = $ssh->exec("> foo.txt"))) {
            echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
        } else {
          echo $stream;
            }       

echo $ssh->getLog();
echo "6. end of code\n";
?>


</body>
</html>
```

So it seems like it stops displaying messages after it is connected to the remote machine?

I am starting to woder if this is actually possible to do? or not due to security issues?

I've installed the SSH2 library from here: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

Also, I used tha same code but instead of using include, i used require:

```
<html> 
<body> 

  TEST <br/>

<?php

echo "1. start\n";
define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib1.0.0');
require('Net/SSH2.php');

echo "2. phpseclib included\n";
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('HOST');
echo "3. after Net_SSH2\n";

if (!$ssh->login("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")) {
        echo "4. login failed";
        exit('Login Failed');
    } else {
       echo "4. login gained\n";
    }

echo "5. after login\n";


    if (!($stream = $ssh->exec("ls"))) {
            echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
        } else {
          echo $stream;
            }

         if (!($stream = $ssh->exec("> foo.txt"))) {
            echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
        } else {
          echo $stream;
            }       

echo $ssh->getLog();
echo "6. end of code\n";
?>


</body>
</html>
```

SOLVED:
By installing the library via PEAR

Comment: turn on display_errors and error_reporting, and try again.

Comment: Why do you have `get_include_path() . get_include_path()` twice?

Comment: @MarcB it seems to be running with no errors. but still "ls" output results are not displayed on the webpage! :/

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem

set_include_path(get_include_path() . get_include_path().'/phpseclib');

There is two issues here, the first as mentioned in the comments are that you are trying to load things from "/your/include/path/your/include/path/phpseclib" instead of "/your/include/path/phpseclib"

If you have installed phpseclib at the include path you should just remove one of the get_include_path and you can get on with your code. Also to read the comments.

Comment: Ok, but though its still the same issue, output is not displayed on the web page. However, if i run the exact same code on the terminal, its connects to the same remote machine and display output on the terminal.

Comment: I have edited the original post. If you have any idea why the same issue is being encountered.

Answer (score 1):

I bet if you changed the `include` to a `require` it wouldn't get as far as you currently are.

And I think `set_include_path(get_include_path() . get_include_path().'/phpseclib');` is your problem as well.

Try this:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib1.0.0');
include('Net/SSH2.php');
```

Comment: Right so, i got this error
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Net_SSH2::getSFTPErrors() in /u/tron5/testpage.php 

I thought it’ll be worth to share the paths. This is where the web page lies: /u/tron5/testpage.php 
Same with the library and ssh: /u/tron5/phpseclib1.0.0/Net/SSH2.php

Comment: You're not calling `getSFTPErrors` in the code that you've posted. Maybe there's more code that you haven't posted?

Comment: I added these two lines in the end
print_r($ssh->getSFTPErrors());

$ssh->getErrors();

Just because i couldn’t yet see the results on the webpage, thought there could be an error

Comment: `getSFTPErrors` is only available in `Net_SFTP`. `Net_SSH2` has `getErrors`. Since `Net_SFTP` extends `Net_SSH2` `Net_SFTP` has both `getSFTPErrors` and `getErrors` but `Net_SSH2` just has `getErrors`.

Comment: ok.. but now the path is set correctly i have no idea why it is not running on the web page? ( i.e. output displayed)

Comment: Do `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` at the start of the file and then do `echo $ssh->getLog()` at the end. Then paste the output into pastebin.com and edit your original post and add the link to it.

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant by "output displayed". I'm assuming you're doing `include`? Try `require` instead. As I said in my answer that should make it so you don't even get the "2. phpseclib included" bit in your output. Anyway, let's do this. Post the full path to phpseclib's Net/SSH2.php and the full path of the file on the webserver that's trying to utilize phpseclib. I am 99% confident that the problem is with your `include_path`.

Comment: Also, altho knowing how to use the `include_path` properly would be beneficial for you, most libraries now - phpseclib included - can be installed via composer. You might have better success with that.

Comment: By displaying the output, i meant, when i execute a command on the server of the machine i've ssh to via the webpage, then i should be able to view the results of those commands on the webpage. For example, here i've executed basic "ls" command and "> foo.txt". When i execute these on the web page I cannot see the listed files nor create a file. Basically it seems like nothing is happening.
Yet, when i run the same php code from a terminal i can see the results, which are the listed files and the foo.txt file being created.

Comment: I tried to use required instead of included. Yet no results of the “ls” being displayed on the web page. (post updated)

Comment: Using require instead of include isn't supposed to fix the problem - it's supposed to confirm the problem. Your code outputs `2. phpseclib included` after the include. My guess is that it *isn't* outputing that when you switch to require. So post the output you're getting with the `include` and post the output you're getting with `require`.

Comment: And don't do the packet handler stuff. I doubt you need it. It's like you're flapping around, trying every odd variant you can find documented when that is, as I've said before, most likely not the problem. Let's stay focused on the includes. Also, something I asked you to do earlier that you didn't respond to...  post the full path to phpseclib's Net/SSH2.php and the full path of the file on the webserver that's trying to utilize phpseclib.

Comment: For both include and require, shall i use this line before "set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib1.0.0');" is it essential? Also I have edited previously to add the paths to the files :). ps. thanks for keeping up with this!

Comment: Any clues what could it be? or is it a dead end unfortunately? :(

Comment: try doing `/u/tron5/phpseclib1.0.0`. i think what you're doing would work if `.` was in get_include_path() but maybe it isn't.